# width of vertical margin which is not set

Tags: css

I have a question about settings of margin in this case:
http://jsfiddle.net/s38Ar/6/

As you see there is vertical margin between two columns. **I would like to know its width and why it looks like this**, because I want to set it myself precisely.

Setting float:left to .column is not acceptable because theme2 should align down to theme4 (as you can see)

CSS

```
    body{background-color:#0d5697;}
.selborder{border:#d7e51c;}
p{font-size:1em;color:white;}
#header{height: 50px;background-color: #666;margin-bottom: 10px;}

h1{font-size:1.5em;color:#dae645;}


@media screen and (max-width: 800px) and (min-width: 448px) {
    #galeria{width:100%;height: 100%;margin:0 auto;}
    #gutter{background-color:white;display:inline-block;width:3%;height:100%;margin-bottom:10px;float:left;display: inline-block;}
    .column2{height:100%;width:94%;float:left;}
    .column{width:49%;background-color:red;vertical-align:bottom;display:inline-block;}
    .work{vertical-align:bottom;}
    .komorka{width:100%;height:100%;}
    .cl2{clear:both;}
}
```

HTML

```
    <body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="galeria">
        <div id="gutter"></div>
        <div class="column2" id="m_col">
            <div class="column" id="col1"><div class="work" id="work1">
                <h1 class="komorka"> theme1 more more more more more more more more more more more theme</h1><img id="paint" class="komorka" src="projekty/asd.png"></img><p class="komorka">1But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness.</p>
            </div></div>
            <div class="column" id="col2"><div class="work" id="work2">
                <h1 class="komorka">theme 2</h1><img class="komorka" id="paint" src="projekty/asd.png"></img><p class="komorka">1But pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness.</p>
            </div></div>
            <div class="column cl2" id="col3"><div class="work" id="work3">
                <h1 class="komorka">theme 3</h1><img class="komorka" id="paint" src="projekty/asd.png"></img><p class="komorka">1But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness.</p>
            </div></div>
            <div class="column" id="col4"><div class="work" id="work4">
                <h1 class="komorka">theme 4</h1><img class="komorka" id="paint" src="projekty/asd.png"></img><p class="komorka">1But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness.</p>
            </div></div>
            <div class="column" id="col5"><div class="work" id="work5">
                <h1 class="komorka">theme 5</h1><img class="komorka" id="paint" src="projekty/asd.png"></img><p class="komorka">1But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness.</p>
            </div></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is due to the `inline-block` display, **it turns both columns into inline elements** (like a `span` or an `a`).

The solution in your case is to manually "remove" the right margin for the left column, like this (just an example for the first two columns):

```
#col1 {
    margin-right: -4px;
}
```

Another solution (less practical, but works), is to **remove the space between `div`s in the HTML code**, this makes the columns fit nicelly, but with dynamic code that might be complicated to get.

I made this example for the first two columns:
http://jsfiddle.net/jackJoe/s38Ar/7/

Comment: this doesnot fit every where . as the main cause remains unknown. :)

Comment: @Anobik what? the cause is simple, as I said, the `inline-block` transforms it into an inline element and that has spaces in the HTML code, that's why. Also, the OP requested "theme2 should align down to theme4" float solutions won't do that (like your answer). I just made one case, the OP would have to do column 3 and 5 also.

Comment: @jackJoe margin-right: -4px seems to be not useful beacause when you have default font size in your browser set different than 16px the margin also changes, anyway I set the margin at -0.25em and it works well on different default font size on firefox but I am not sure if it will be ok on other browsers or font types. In the second aproach everything seems to be ok, do you say it may be complicated when I use JavaScript with the divs?

Comment: setting  fixed value only will work if a non responsive design has to  be made

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you require

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8GFbz/)

The change in css is as follows

added

```
.column:nth-child(even){
float:right;
width:50% !important;
}

.column:nth-child(odd){
    float:left;
        width:50% !important;
}
```

width will be 50% as to reduce the gap. It is not a MARGIN :)now you can put individual margins to divs :)

Comment: In your approach theme2 div is not aligned bottom to theme4, that is important to me